# All apps built in xcode crashes with "Termination Reason: Namespace Codesigning, Code 0x1"

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm a very sporadic Xcode developer. I have a few apps that I only use locally on my personal computer and I update them from time to time.

Today, I cannot get anything built inside Xcode to run anymore. Not when achieving, nor debug. When trying to launch the app built it crashes with the following error:

Termination Reason: Namespace Codesigning, Code 0x1.

This goes for everything I compile now. I checked my signing settings in Xcode and it looks the same as it did before. I've googled for an hour and nothing tried works. Apparently, signing apps have gotten a bigger f***ing nightmare then I comprehend and I don't have the time to take a 10 hour course in how to get this crap running again. Bad attitude perhaps but the thing is, I do not distribute apps at all, I only want to code for my local, personal needs. Is there any quick fix to get things working again without spending major time over Apple dittidatts?

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried this? https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/664657

Comment: I totally feel your pain.   We have to deal with code signing headaches because some people insist on doing bad things to other people's info and devices, but it does make it a pain when you want to just do something locally and don't keep updated certs.  So first thing, in your projects, settings (to of the file project navigator on the left - select the project). Go to Signing and Capabilities, set to "Sign to run locally"

Comment: Just to avoid other headaches, since these are projects for your own personal local use, if you see "App Sandbox" delete it by clicking on the "x" on the far right of that panel.  You can keep "Hardened Runtime".  You only need App Sandbox if you're going to distribute your app.

Comment: Oh, and also in the menu bar "Product -> Clean Build Folder"

Comment: Oh thank you Chip, sign to run locally totally fixed this mess. App sandbox is already trashed. I'm not using hardened runtime either. It's incredible how much crap that has to be done just for a local compile. Sigh.

Comment: Seaspell seen it but haven't had the time to look into it much. The suggestion from chip was exactly what I was looking for: a toggle.